# angular : npm install -g @angular/cli npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, frontend, crud

I want learn angular
I install the Node version  18.13.0
and when I want to install angular cli  whit this command
`npm install -g @angular/cli`
I have this problem :
`npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND'` npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo'
'npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND'
'npm ERR! network request to [https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli'](https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli%27) 'failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org'
'npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.'
'npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have' 'network settings.'
'npm ERR! network'
'npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the'
'npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help' 'config'

'npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:'
'npm ERR! C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\20230117T19_14_37_347Z-debug-0.log`

what I should do to resolve this problem  thanks you
my OS is windows 11

Answer (score 0):

Your command is correct.

The error is a network problem due to the registry.npmjs.org site.

Try it again.

This morning i had it too.

Unfortunatly it can happen.

[Here](https://status.npmjs.org/history) you see the status.

Today they where some issues with some packages.

Anyway run this to clean your environment.

```
npm cache verify
```